# What is cut-in voltage of a transistor?

Tags: voltage, transistors, cut-in

Some literature talk about cut-in voltage but couldn't find a clear explanation.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an officially recognized term by any standards body, but in the south-eastern United States (and possibly elsewhere) "cut-in" (cut-on) is the colloquial opposite to "cut-off" (cut-out). It is used by many in everyday life in reference to light switches -- "cut-on the lights" = "turn on the lights".

Ergo, this is the informal name for the threshold voltage that is the transition point between the cut-off and active regions of the transistor.